# GNOME Tweaks app loses its desktop button after first installed

Tags: gnome, kali-linux

[image: Screenshot of GNOME Tweaks]

In the title bar there is no desktop button.

This was observed in the [GNOME Tweaks app](https://launchpad.net/gnome-tweaks) of Gnome 3.30.0 in Kali Linux 2018.4  .

A) I did not find the documentation anywhere. This desktop button is present by default at the first installation.

B) The program is installed by default in the distribution.

С) I am tried to reinstall gnome tweaks, but it did not help. Before that, I broke the operating system, which did not start. I created before that a snapshot in timeshift. Did the restore and found this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question. In the version of gnome 3.30 there are no more desktop icons.

The developer answered me at gitlab.gnome.org.

> That is intentionally because no "desktop icons feature" exists
>   anymore. Hence I am closing this task.

[enter link description here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/issues/171)